# Buttons to run Maven targets in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans

I'd like to have a button to run (custom) Maven targets in NetBeans 6.9. Hot-keys would also be nice. Is this possible?

If it is not possible: is there something like a console where I could Maven commands directly?

Comment: Bounty is for an answer that lets me save the custom goal as a button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 11):

In NetBeans 6.9: 
Right-click on the project -> Custom -> Goals. Make sure to check "Remember as: ". You can run this by  Right-click on the project -> Custom -> "myRememberAsName"

I don't know if there is an easy way to assign this to a button or a short cut.

Comment: It's the same also in NetBeans 6.8 and 6.7

Comment: Thanks. I've already known this but looking for something more convenient.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using custom goals you can create a custom profile.

In the project properties, go in pane **Configurations**, add a new one, select it then click on **Activate**.

In the pane **Run** select your custom configuration.

Then in pane **Actions** select your custom configuration and add/edit the goals you need.

The goals that are already present can't be removed but you can delete the content in "Execute goals" and they will do nothing.

Then when you will click on Run button the goals you have set will be execute.

PS : There is a console in Netbeans (Window->Output->Terminal) but in 6.9 it's still experimental (and pretty inattractive), the one in 7.1.1 works well.

Comment: This almost deserves the bounty, but it requires you swapping configurations to run multiple different maven goals at different times, which is not what I am looking for. I just want to have buttons on the toolbar set to "jetty:run" "liquibase:update" etc, as I want to run them individually and only sometimes.

Comment: I've tried to give the best "possible" solution. I've try to look at shortcuts but I don't find a way to create new actions related to Maven. Unfortunatelly the examples are quite inexistant for that... All ressource are here if you found the strength to do it! http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ

Comment: Today I'm so confused cause of this, I want to make custom actions too for my project but I don't know whats wrong when I try to add custom actions that new actions always disabled and I can't add execute goals.

Answer (score 2):

My solution isn't exactly what you are looking for, but it is worth mentioning.  First, run your custom target in Netbeans.  Once you do that, in the "Run" menu you see the "Repeat xxx" at the bottom.  This menu has a keyboard shortcut (Command F11 on Mac, not sure what it is on other operating systems).  Thus, using this keyboard shortcut, you can run the same maven goal repeatedly.