# Equivalent of mvn -U in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

How do I tell Netbeans 7 to check and get the latest SNAPSHOT version? It seems I either have to wait for the time threshold to pass or do the forced check on the command line; `mvn -U compile`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413270/buttons-to-run-maven-targets-in-netbeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Netbeans 7.2 in the *Output* pane there is a yellow icon on the left with tooltip *Re-run with different parameters*. Clicking that will open a dialog. Select **Update Snapshots**.

[image: Netbeans: Re-run with different paramaters dialog]